# Writing a For Loop in R for survival analysis

Tags: for-loop

I am having issues extracting survival data for specific times ( years 1,5 and 10). i tried summary(fit, times = c(1,5,10)), but this doesn't extract the right survival estimates.

I have written the following code to censor the data to include only the cohort for year 1 and extract survival for year 1:

```
TIME <- 1

tmp <- data1[data1$tstart < TIME*365.25,]
tmp <- tmp[!duplicated(tmp$id,fromLast = T),]
tmp$status[tmp$time >TIME*365.25] <- 0
tmp$time[tmp$time > TIME*365.25] <- TIME*365.25

fit <- survfit(Surv(time/365.25, status) ~ drug_dosage, data=tmp)
fit_year <- summary(fit, times = TIME)
```

My question is how can I create a loop for time to include the years 5 and 10. Thank you in advance.

This is a sample of what my data looks like.
        id time status  tstart
    1  2131 2311      0      0
    2  2131 2311      0     17
    3  2131 2311      0     50
    4  2131 2311      0    105
    5  2131 2311      0    133
    6  2131 2311      0    153
    7  2131 2311      0    209
    8  2131 2311      0    238
    9  2131 2311      0    276
    10 2131 2311      0    317

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. It would be great if the sample data you provide corresponds to the code chunk you provide in order to ensure reproductivity.

```
for (i in c(1,5,10)){
  TIME <- i
  tmp <- data1[data1$tstart < TIME*365.25,]
  tmp <- tmp[!duplicated(data$id,fromLast = T),]
  tmp$status[tmp$time >TIME*365.25] <- 0
  tmp$time[tmp$time > TIME*365.25] <- TIME*365.25

  fit <- survfit(Surv(time/365.25, status) ~ drug_dosage, data=tmp)
  fit_year <- summary(fit, time = TIME)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I think it has worked but when i try to look at fit_year it only shows the year 1. Do you know how I can look at year 5 and 10?

Comment: That is because It because it only saves the last summary the loop went into (you should see the year 10 and not 1). You could try replacing `fit_year <- summary(fit, time = TIME)` with `assign(paste0("fit_year_",i), summary(fit, time = TIME))` . This will create 3 different frames `fit_year_1`,`fit_year_5` and `fit_year_10` . One summary table for each of the years you are interested in. Hope this helps